# Using role in XHTML 1.0 strict validated

Tags: xhtml, xhtml-1.0-strict

Is there a validated alternative to using role for XHTML 1.0 strict?

For example,

Thanks.

Comment: The `role` attribute is not part of XHTML 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. There isn't (assuming you want to stay within XHTML 1.0).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `rel` attribute as a substitute for the `role` attribute.